# redirect to page only once every 24 hour using mobiledetect script in php

Tags: php

I have the following code :

```
include("Mobile_Detect.php");

$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
$parsedUrll = curPageURL();
$wwwtom = str_replace("www", "m", $parsedUrll);
header("location: $wwwtom");
exit;
}
```

Which redirects website visitors to the mobile website if they are using a mobile device. the problem is that the code redirects all the time making it impossible for mobile users to access the computer website. 
I want the mobile users to have the option to go back to the normal website if they clicked on a button. but I cannot really do that because of the redirection code that I have now. How can I fix the code, so it will only redirect once every 24 hours.
suggestions, ideas, solution, all are welcome.

Comment: Set a cookie on redirect to non_mobile site, and if mobile is detected check to see that the cookie is not present and then direct if it is not. Make cookie expire in 24hrs.

Comment: @cryptic I cannot set a cookie because cookies work only on `ANSI` file format. my PHP files are in `UTF-8 without BOM` which does not allow using cookies. I cannot change my files to `ANSI` because the website language is not supported by the `ANSI`

Comment: link (to the official docs) or didn't happen @shnisaka

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: And where does it say UTF-8 encoded PHP files cannot create cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for the mobile detection:

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';

$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile() && !isset($_COOKIE['use_desktop'])) // check if mobile and does not prefer desktop
{
    $parsedUrll = curPageURL();
    $wwwtom = str_replace('www', 'm', $parsedUrll);
    header("Location: $wwwtom");
    exit;
}
```

Use link like this for going to desktop, or use a `$_GET` query:

```
<a href='desktop.php'>View Desktop Version</a>
```

In `desktop.php` use this:

```
define('COOKIE_LIFETIME_ONE_DAY', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + 86400);
setcookie('use_desktop', '1', COOKIE_LIFETIME_ONE_DAY);
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/"); // direct to desktop site
exit;
```